# Eigen - return type of .cwiseProduct?

Tags: eigen, rcpp

I am writing a function in RcppEigen for weighted covariances. In one of the steps I want to take column i and column j of a matrix, X, and compute the cwiseProduct, which should return some kind of vector. The output of cwiseProduct will go into an intermediate variable which can be reused many times. From the docs it seems [cwiseProduct](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1MatrixBase.html#aec042ef07f9f91d8e3631c9c477aa911) returns a [CwiseBinaryOp](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1CwiseBinaryOp.html), which itself takes two types. My cwiseProduct operates on two column vectors, so I thought the correct return type should be `Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::ColXpr, Eigen::ColXpr>`, but I get the error *no member named ColXpr in namespace Eigen*

```
#include <RcppEigen.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppEigen)]]

Rcpp::List Crossprod_sparse(Eigen::MappedSparseMatrix<double> X, Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXd> W) {
  int K = W.cols();
  int p = X.cols();

  Rcpp::List crossprods(W.cols());

  for (int i = 0; i < p; i++) {
    for (int j = i; j < p; j++) {
      Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::ColXpr, Eigen::ColXpr> prod = X.col(i).cwiseProduct(X.col(j));
      for (int k = 0; k < K; k++) {
        //double out = prod.dot(W.col(k));
      }
    }
  }
  return crossprods;
}
```

I have also tried saving into a SparseVector

```
Eigen::SparseVector<double> prod = X.col(i).cwiseProduct(X.col(j));
```

as well as computing, but not saving at all

```
X.col(i).cwiseProduct(X.col(j));
```

If I don't save the product at all, the functions returns very quickly, hinting that cwiseProduct is not an expensive function. When I save it into a SparseVector, the function is extremely slow, making me think that SparseVector is not the right return type and Eigen is doing extra work to get it into that type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recall that Eigen relies on expression templates, so if you don't assign an expression then this expression is essentially a no-op. In your case, assigning it to a `SparseVector` is the right thing to do. Regarding speed, make sure to compile with compiler optimizations ON (like `-O3`).

Nonetheless, I believe there is a faster way to write your overall computations. For instance, are you sure that all `X.col(i).cwiseProduct(X.col(j))` are non empty? If not, then the second loop should be rewritten to iterate over the sparse set of overlapping columns only. Loops could also be interchanged to leverage efficient matrix products.